# JOptionPane botão cancelar

Tags: java

No seguinte código, ele solicita que seja preenchido o nome, porém caso não digite nada, e clico em cancelar ele me retorna uma mensagem (O nome que informou foi Null).

Minha dúvida é como que faço para ao clica em cancelar ele diretamente fechar a aplicação ou aparecer outra mensagem, não aparecer o "null".

Segue a parte do código:

```
mensagem.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String nome;
        nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual seu nome?"); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(janela, "O nome que informou foi:\n"+nome);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mensagem.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String nome;
        nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual seu nome?"); 
        if(nome != null) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(janela, "O nome que informou foi:\n"+nome);
        else {
            //faz outra coisa
        }
   }
});
```